# Disable B frames in Android MediaCodec

Tags: android

I want to encode with Android `MediaCodec` using `H.264` high profile. I tried to disable b frames, but failed.

Any suggestions, Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a way? it looks like a Profile option but I didn't find where to config

Answer (score 0):

This was added in API 29.  Can be set to zero, which it says is the default.  Other than that, you'll probably have to use Baseline.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat#KEY_MAX_B_FRAMES